# Restore previous window position on buffer switch in Emacs

Tags: emacs, buffer, window-position

I split windows to view two different parts of the selected buffer simultaneously. If I switch to another buffer in one of the windows and then switch back to the original buffer, I'll lose the previous window position---I'll see the same parts of the selected buffer in both windows. How can I restore window positions amongst buffer switches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think if you use `clone-indirect-buffer-other-window`(bound to <kbd>C-x 4 c</kbd> by default) to obtain the two windows, the window positions will be preserved independently.  See [Indirect Buffers](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indirect-Buffers.html).

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. I've been using Emacs for several years now, but didn't know about this feature.